# Prove that $T$ is normal if and only if $u, x$ is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix $u,x\in V$. Define $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ By
$$Tv=\langle v,u\rangle x$$ for every $v\in V$

Prove that $T$ is normal if and only if $u, x$ is linearly dependent.

I was applying definition of Normal operator but I was not getting the answer.

Comment: What did you get as the adjoint $T^*$?

Comment: You have removed the definition of $T$, making the question to be nonsense. This action raises some suspects, so I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the adjoint $T^*$ is the operator $T^*\colon V\rightarrow V$ such that $\langle Ty,z\rangle=\langle y,T^*z\rangle$ for all $y,z\in V$. To compute this, we need the sesquilinearity of $\langle , \rangle$:
$$\langle Ty,z \rangle=\langle\langle y,u \rangle x, z\rangle=\langle y,u \rangle\langle x,z \rangle=\langle y,\overline{\langle x,z \rangle}u \rangle=\langle y,T^*z \rangle.$$
Thus $T^*z=\overline{\langle x,z \rangle}u$. Plugging this into the definition of normal $T^*T=TT^*$, we get the equality
$$\langle x,x \rangle\langle v,u \rangle u=\langle u,u \rangle\langle v,x \rangle x$$
for all $v\in V$. WLOG $u,x$ are unit vectors, so this is equivalent to saying that
$$\langle v,u \rangle u=\langle v,x \rangle x$$
for all $v\in V$. Why does imply that $u,x$ are linearly dependent?

Comment: To finish off, using the representation as derived by charletoncrab, compute $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ and compare.

Comment: To see why $\left< v,u \right>u=\left< v,x \right>x$ implies linear dependency: Otherwise $\left< v,u \right>=\left< v,x \right> =0$ for each $v$ but we know the only vector orthogonal to every vector is $0$ so $u=x=0$ but $0$ and $0$ are linearly dependent by definition.